# Error in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I develop a web application using asp.net and that application totally working in localhost and also live. But when come heavy requests into our web application getting this error.  **Error shows on browserCaps tag in web.config**

Error description is -

> an error occurred during the processing of the configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

I set a `CacheDuration` on my webmethod.

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 1000)]
```

This is the webmethod ,

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 1000)]
[SoapHeader("Credentials")]
public string GetData(string input_01)
{
    string output_01;
    //doing some stuff 
    return output_01;
}
```

Is that error is comming because **cache** ???

[image: This is the error report]

If you want more details please comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Error Description is not visible clearly in screen shot

Comment: @ShakeerHussain this is the error description - 'an error occurred during the processing of the configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.'

Comment: In IIS, AppPool set .NET Framework version 4.0

Comment: @ShakeerHussain yeah. version is OK.

Comment: MobileCapabilities class is obsolete from .Net 4.0. Try changing the framework version to 3.5. Refer this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mobile.mobilecapabilities(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It is working on live also. But when coming heavy number of requests it provide an error on web.config. Eg. when coming 15 web requests per second.